# Are linear processes stationary?

Tags: time-series, stochastic-processes, cointegration, stationarity

I am reading Soren Johansen's book on cointegration and I'm wonder about the following definition:

> **Definition 3.1**. A linear process is defined by $Y_t=\sum_{i=0}^\infty C_i\epsilon_{t-i}$, $t=0, 1, \dots$ where $C(z)=\sum_{i=0}^\infty C_iz^i$ is convergent for $|z|\leq 1+\delta$ for some $\delta>0$.

Nothing is said about the properties of such a linear process, and I don't really get what this linear process *is*. I can see that e.g. a vector of random walks is ruled out (since $C_i=I$ and $C(z)$ would not converge), but can we say that such a linear process is always stationary?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check the conditions for stationarity using his definition. A little above the definition it is mentioned that the $\epsilon_{t}$ are iid with mean zero and variance $\Omega$ (implicitly assumed finite). Hence, thanks to the convergence conditions mentioned in the defintion, it is OK to compute

$$ E(Y_t)= \sum_{i=0}^\infty C_iE(\epsilon_{t-i})=0$$

and similarly for the (autoco-)variance(s). As the moments do not depend on $t$, we have stationarity. In fact, citing Brockwell/Davis, Introduction to Time Series and Forecasting, p51:

> The class of linear time series models, which includes the class of
>   autoregressive moving-average (ARMA) models, provides a general
>   framework for studying stationary processes. In fact, every
>   second-order stationary process is either a linear process or can be
>   transformed to a linear process by subtracting a deterministic
>   component. This result is known as Wold’s decomposition and is
>   discussed in Section 2.6.